# scrape data from jsp web with Nokogiri or other ruby tools?

Tags: ruby

there is a jsp web:
http://xbrl.cninfo.com.cn/XBRL/allinfo.jsp?stkid=000002&getyear=2005&nowpage=Info.jsp&reportType=GB0110
can i scrape data from it with Nokogiri or other ruby tools?

Comment: You probably mean scrape, not scrap. What did you try? What problem do you have? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, if site owner allowed you to do that.

but looks like the data are in javascript like

```
...
arrallvalues[18].addValuesbyfisId('0.842');
arrallvalues[19].addYearsbyfisId('2005年');
arrallvalues[19].addYearsbyfisId('2006年');
arrallvalues[19].addYearsbyfisId('2007年');
arrallvalues[19].addYearsbyfisId('2008年');
arrallvalues[19].addYearsbyfisId('2009年');
arrallvalues[19].addValuesbyfisId('21992392061.30');
arrallvalues[19].addValuesbyfisId('49919840381.13');
arrallvalues[19].addValuesbyfisId('100094467908.29');
arrallvalues[19].addValuesbyfisId('119236579721.09');
arrallvalues[19].addValuesbyfisId('137608554829.39');
arrallvalues[20].addYearsbyfisId('2005年');
arrallvalues[20].addYearsbyfisId('2006年');
arrallvalues[20].addYearsbyfisId('2007年');
arrallvalues[20].addYearsbyfisId('2008年');
...
```

So, I doubt, you will end up in writing analyzer your self.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question deserves negative votes, I think there is no need to write an analyzer yourself because there is JavaScript. I have coded scrappers myself where data is in Javascript. Ruby has libraries to evaluate js (spidermonkey, johnson). Something like this, however this would crash the js interpreter, did not investigate why, but I would guess the chinesse language

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'johnson'
require 'open-uri'

base_url = 'http://xbrl.cninfo.com.cn/XBRL'
page_url = base_url + '/allinfo.jsp?stkid=000002&getyear=2005&nowpage=Info.jsp&reportType=GB0110'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page_url))

doc.xpath("html/head/script").each do |el|
  src = el.attributes['src']
  if not src.text.empty?
    # load remote js
    Johnson.evaluate(open(base_url + '/' + src).read)
  else
    Johnson.evaluate(el.text)
  end
end

puts Johnson.evaluate("arrallvalues[0]")
```